# How to animate character switching outfit/identities

Tags: animation

So, for a project I'm attempting to create a character transform into her "royal" outfit, like a superhero or a magical girl.

[image]
This is just a quick diagram example, but I want her other form to be revealed from the top to the bottom with particles intersecting, but I've been stuck of solving this out in latest versions of Blender. (I've attempted to do a "mask" with the two meshes but wasn't really successful)

Are there any resources or how I can be able to accomplish animating this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add a cube to use as the boolean object. For one outfit, add a Boolean modifier set to *Intersect*, and for the second, add a Boolean modifier set to *Difference*. Now, if you animated the cube moving down over the two outfits, the first outfit will show up inside cube, and the second will show up outside. You  need to hide the cube in the Viewport and the Render. Also, you need to match the movement of the cube with the particle effect.